# Apache Ignite cache operation failure

Tags: docker, redis, ignite, jedis

I've installed Ignite using a docker image from docker hub. Ignite server node starts correctly. But I get the following exception when trying to update cache:

```
[SEVERE][rest-#35%null%][GridCacheCommandHandler] Failed to execute cache command: GridRestCacheRequest [cacheName=null, cacheFlags=0, ttl=null, super=GridRestRequest [destId=null, clientId=466b7ff5-c303-452e-8f2d-97d59c753de5, addr=null, cmd=CACHE_PUT]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to find cache for given cache name (null for default cache): null
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.handlers.cache.GridCacheCommandHandler.localCache(GridCacheCommandHandler.java:754)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.handlers.cache.GridCacheCommandHandler.executeCommand(GridCacheCommandHandler.java:677)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.handlers.cache.GridCacheCommandHandler.handleAsync(GridCacheCommandHandler.java:468)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.GridRestProcessor.handleRequest(GridRestProcessor.java:264)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.GridRestProcessor.access$100(GridRestProcessor.java:87)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.GridRestProcessor$2.body(GridRestProcessor.java:153)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[14:57:18,637][SEVERE][rest-#35%null%][GridRestProcessor] Failed to handle request: CACHE_PUT
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to find cache for given cache name (null for default cache): null
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.handlers.cache.GridCacheCommandHandler.localCache(GridCacheCommandHandler.java:754)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.handlers.cache.GridCacheCommandHandler.executeCommand(GridCacheCommandHandler.java:677)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.handlers.cache.GridCacheCommandHandler.handleAsync(GridCacheCommandHandler.java:468)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.GridRestProcessor.handleRequest(GridRestProcessor.java:264)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.GridRestProcessor.access$100(GridRestProcessor.java:87)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.GridRestProcessor$2.body(GridRestProcessor.java:153)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You should create cache before you will start using it. Use getOrCreateCache method.

You could read more information in [doc](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jcache#section-ignitecache) and check this [example](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/CacheApiExample.java) which use cache api.

Also, there are a lot examples in apache ignite for various use cases.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, i'm just a little bit confused , i start the ignite server from a docker image from Linux.

i tried what did you suggest and it works but i'm not sure if the ignite server running at the moment it's the Apache ignite docker image.

could you please explain how can i create the cache form Linux for the apache ignite docker image

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you try to access cache when you got this exception?

Comment: Ignite is partially Redis compliant and enables users to store and retrieve distributed data from Apache Ignite caches using any Redis compatible client.

Comment: i'm using jedis (redis client)

Comment: but i got this exception when im using redis-cli on linux and even when i'm using jedis (redis client) with a java programme

Comment: You can add cache configuration to ignite config file, here you can find some examples: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-modes, cache with this configuration will start automatically.